# Can I search images on Safari using a text in the text field on a third-party app using shortcut?

Tags: ios, shortcut

I would like to search a list of images (either on Safari or Google Chrome) on iOS, from a text that is in a text field on a third-party app.

In details:

- Use a third-party dictionary app to search the meaning of a word. I type in the word on the text field and get a list of words.
- I pick up the relevant word on the table.
- If I find it hard to understand the meaning of the word, open the Safari and type in the word on the search bar to see the list of images on the word.

Now, I would like to make it automatic with shortcut app, if possible. The dictionary app shows the word on the textfield (UITextField I think). I think if you copy the word you could use the shortcut, but it is too cumbersome on iOS so I want to skip it.

So is this possible...?

Answer (score 1):

One is welcome to invoke shortcuts or other automation techniques to do so, but here are my approaches:

- Select the word: hold on it, and tap "select". Then the tooltip menu changes to "cut", "copy", "lookup", "share" and depending on the app, "speak", "highlight" etc.

  Use "lookup". If you find appropriate meaning, great! otherwise, scroll to the bottom and tap "search web" and it will shoot to Safari.
- If you know how to pronounce, tell Siri to get some images. Use a command that doesn't invoke photos app, rather "web search".